# Testing suspend/resume in UWP apps with Template10

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, uwp

I'm working on a Windows 10 UWP app and I'm using the [Template10 library](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10).  In the view model of the main page of my app, I have this code to try to handle suspend and resume:

```
    public override void OnNavigatedTo(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> state)
    {
        if (state.Any())
        {
            NumberOfQuizQuestions = (int)state["QuizQuestions"];
            state.Clear();
        }
    }

    public override Task OnNavigatedFromAsync(IDictionary<string, object> state, bool suspending)
    {
        if (suspending)
        {
            state["QuizQuestions"] = this.NumberOfQuizQuestions;
        }
        return base.OnNavigatedFromAsync(state, suspending);
    }
```

My question is: how can I test that this is working right?  When I launch the app in the debugger, I have the Lifecycle Toolbar showing, so when I click "Suspend and shutdown" the code in `OnNavigatedFromAsync()` runs and `suspending` is true, which seems correct.  But no matter how I try to launch the app, `state` is empty in `OnNavigatedTo()`.  Is this expected?

Comment: The code you've posted is right and I tested your code with a Minimal project template, I can get `QuizQuestions` from `state` when launching after "Suspend and shutdown". You can also try with a Minimal project template to see if it works.

Comment: A long shot, but try debugging the code, normally resume should first be picked up in the bootstrapper ( https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Common/BootStrapper.cs )

Comment: Thanks @JayZuo-MSFT!  It worked for me with the Minimal project template, so I guess I'm doing something wrong in one of the methods in App.xaml.cs.  But this is a big step!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I quickly and reliably test/debug a resume scenario on a Windows 10 PC is as follows:

1. In Visual Studio, run your application without the debugger attached (ctrl-F5)
2. In the application, navigate to the state where you want to suspend your application.
3. Switch to Visual Studio and launch the application under the debugger (F5 - Debug, or F10 - Step Over or F11 - Step Into).

When you start the debugging session in step 3, Visual Studio will first compile and deploy your application. Of course, since the application is running, it must be first suspended and then terminated.

Then the application is started again, with the debugger attached, and the previous execution state is "terminated". Place your breakpoints and debug.

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy your application to a Windows 10 Mobile Emulator or an actual device. Then you can just run the app, go to your startscreen and return to it after a while to trigger the different states. This will not break your debugging session.

Comment: Hmm, I thought if the debugger was still attached that meant that the process didn't actually shut down, which means my save/restore code doesn't need to run.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.  The problem is that Template10 uses the tile's ID to determine whether the launch is coming from a primary or secondary tile - if the tile's name is "App", it's the primary tile.  In this case, I was using an upgraded project from Windows Phone 8.0, and for some reason my Package.appxmanifest had an Application tag with an Id that was not "App".